# Select a table cell via python and PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have the code below and I just want to find the command that selects a specific cell and NOT a column or a row.

for example:

```
QTableWidget().item(2,0)
```

the code is :

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = QTableWidget()
    tableItem = QTableWidgetItem()

    # initiate table
    table.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget Example @pythonspot.com")
    table.resize(400, 250)
    table.setRowCount(4)
    table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(["Number 0ne","Number Two","Number Three","Number Four"])
    table.setColumnCount(2)
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Age'])


    for x in range(4):
        for y in range(2):
             table.setItem(x, y, QTableWidgetItem("Item (%d ,  %d)"% ((x+1),(y+1))))


    # show table
    table.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I wanna know what is the best reference for PyQt commands which helps the coder about the command's arguments?

for example, where is the best place to inform about what can be the `QString` in this command: `setAccessibleName(self, QString)`

Comment: Do you want to get the item from a specific position or select it visually, ie it is colored in a different color?

Comment: `table.item(2, 0).setSelected(True)`.

Comment: [PyQt4 Class Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `item` method, `table.item(2,0)` for example.
Using it in your code would return `<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x7f5154057af8>`, which is the object handle for the widget located in the `(2,0)` table's cell.

The problem with the code you mentioned (`QTableWidget().item(2,0)`) is that you need to call it from the instance of the `QTableWidget` class, i.e. `table` in your case.

You could use either the [PyQt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html) or the [PySide](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/) docs, which are very similar to the PyQt (most of the commands are exactly the same, but caution is advised) but have better readability.

[PySide Docs for QTableWidget](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.itemAt) for example.

Comment: itemAt() returns an item with respect to the geometric position x, y, not with respect to row x and column y. I think the author does not want that.

Comment: When you run `table.itemAt(2.0)`, this returns the item in row `0` and column `0`, since `(2, 0)` is in pixels.

Comment: Take the time to be sure of your publication, since you are going to confuse beginners. Also I would recommend reading the Qt4 documentation if you are using PyQt4 or PySide as it is very good.

Comment: Indeed, you are completely right.  But to be honest I never liked the Qt4 docs haha. I don't come from a C background and never found the site to be very clear. Pyside docs on the other hand is very easy to read for me.. Thanks for the tips

Comment: It does not refer to the syntax of the function, but to the meaning of the function, as in this case you were confusing between `item()` and `itemAt()`.  :P